# How to split a string javascript

Tags: javascript, string, split

I have a string `"2FrankfurtLondon3ParisPortland"`. I want to split it as

```
2
Frankfurt
London
3
Paris 
Portland
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow, can you please share what you have tried so far and what you're stuck with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach uses a regex split:

```js
var input = "2FrankfurtLondon3ParisPortland";
var parts = input.split(/(?<=\d)(?=\D)|(?<=\D)(?=\d)|(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])/);
console.log(parts);
```

The regex uses only lookarounds, and says to split when:

```regex
(?<=\d)(?=\D)          digit preceding, non digit following
|
(?<=\D)(?=\d)          non digit preceding, digit following
|
(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])/)  lowercase preceding, uppercase following
```

We could also use `match` here, for a possibly simpler solution:

```js
var input = "2FrankfurtLondon3ParisPortland";
var parts = input.match(/\d+|[A-Z][a-z]+/g);
console.log(parts);
```

Comment: Shows invalid regular expression

Comment: @RemyaKamal If the first version doesn't work for you, then maybe you're using an older version of JavaScript.  In that case, use my second `match` solution.